# Who is responsible for assigning interrupt ID?

Tags: timer, arm, interrupt, arm64

I'm currently reading linux timer source on MTK armv8 platform as a software developer.
According to "IHI0069C_gic_architecture_specification.pdf" from ARM. Each type of PPI(Private Peripheral Interrupt) has an interrupt ID which is obtained from "ICC_IAR1_EL1".

However document from arm only SUGGEST what type should use what interrupt ID. (page 2-32) And i cannot see anyone who write interrupt ID into register.

So arm doesn't write it, software doesn't write it. Then who did it? And where i can get the document of which interrupt ID stands for which type of IRQ?

Comment: it would be application specific yes? so linux, bsd, xyz rtos, etc can vary yes?  Why would arm be involved?  as you read and commented on here it gives you rules as to what arms limitations are, likewise states IMPLEMENTATION
DEFINED which is often code in this context for whomever compiled the logic, meaning the chip vendor not arm.  so on a chip by chip basis you would need to know the implementation which should be documented by then and then from that pick for your application.

Comment: However i'm pretty sure, software didn't write this interrupt ID. It pretty like "someone defines virtual timer ID is 27". I thought it would be ARM and it turns out not. Now i don't know who is the one really defines it

Comment: the designers of the software, the os, rtos, baremetal, etc.  I would expect it to be part of the system design based on the hardware features available and desired.  Cant imagine why ARM would have anything to do with it.